# not able to get list of all models in a pyramid project

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, models, pyramid, pylons

I am trying to write admin console for my pyramid project. 
I am trying to get a list of all classes defined in models. Is there any way to get these?

Comment: This question needs more details, source code and such. In current form the reader have no idea what you are asking. Please edit your question for clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get list of all SQLAlchemy models you can do it through a registry exposed through `Base` class:

```
models = {}

for name, cls in Base._decl_class_registry.items():

    if name == "_sa_module_registry":
        continue

    models[name] = cls
```

Comment: Thanks Mikko.. The above information is what I was looking for.. It answers my question.  I took a break to build admin interface.. but started on it again this week and this helped me to get through..